# How do I figure out why some apps won't connect?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, connection

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), and have a couple of apps giving problems connecting at work. I'm using Socialite to keep track of Facebook, Twitter and RSS feeds, and also use Adium for chatting on Gtalk, Facebook and Skype.

When running Socialite, the application tries to update indefinitely, I suspect this is because of a blocked port.

Also when trying to connect Facebook chat on Adium, the screen where Facebook authorisation is supposed to happen stays in a loading state as well.

How can I figure out which ports these applications are trying to use, and if not port blocking, what the issue is behind them not connecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Private Eye](http://radiosilenceapp.com/private-eye) might be what you're looking for. It's a free network monitor for Mac OS X. It shows where it tries to connect, so you could test the domains manually to see if they're blocked.